# Append wildcards in SELECT with MySQL

Tags: mysql, select, where-in

Using MySQL:

I have a table 'city':
id, 'name', 'serving'
contains:

```
'1', 'Athens', 'Athens, Etowah, Madisonville'
'2', 'Etowah', 'Etowah, Athens, Madisonville, Niota'
'3', 'Madisonville', 'Madisonville, Niota, Athens, Etowah'
'4', 'Soddy Daisy', 'Soddy Daisy, Decatur, Graysville'
'5', 'Signal Mountain', 'Signal Mountain, Walden, Jasper, Kimball'
```

I have a table 'zipcodes':
id, 'zipcode', 'cityname'
contains:

```
'1','00000','Athens'
'2', '00001', 'Dayton'
'3', '00002', 'Soddy Daisy'
```

So in city, 'serving' is a comma-delimited string of areas surrounding a major city 'name' starting with the major city.

I can get a list from my database using this statement:

```
SELECT serving FROM `city` WHERE serving LIKE '%Athens%'
```

What I am trying to get is the major city 'name' from the 'city' list where the 'cityname' is NOT in serving. Major bonus if it returned a list where the 'cityname' is prioritized by position in the string. The goal initially is to make sure I have every 'cityname' in zipcodes covered in the 'serving' field of city.

Desired output
Example '00001' Dayton - (NOT IN serving): Dayton

Bonus;
Then when finding '00000' Athens (IN serving): Athens, Etowah, Madisonville

I have tried:

```
SELECT z.cityname FROM zipcodes z
WHERE z.cityname NOT IN (
    SELECT c.serving FROM city c
        WHERE c.serving LIKE CONCAT('''%',z.cityname,'%'''))
```

But this isn't finding any matches in the city 'serving' list.

I tried formatting the string differently but I am getting errors.

```
SELECT z.cityname FROM zipcodes z
WHERE z.cityname NOT IN (
    SELECT c.serving FROM city c
        WHERE c.serving LIKE '%' + z.cityname + '%')
```

So I am figuring it is in my string for the wildcard match is where this is failing. So any advice would be greatly appreciated.

My database experience is mostly MSSQL and searching here and google is not rendering what I am looking for as to why my SELECT isn't working.

Thank you!

Edit: added more samples for the datatables

Comment: It would be better if you posted sample data and expected results to clarify your requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you wanted to find zip codes that are not "served" by any of the cities you can use:

```
SELECT z.zipcode, z.cityname 
FROM zipcodes z
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT * 
  FROM city c
  WHERE c.serving LIKE CONCAT('%',z.cityname,'%')
)
```

See [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/azxwac642akqvsgn1dMvXP/0).

Comment: Ok, this is more in the lines of the initial question and provides me the answer to work past my problem. Both answers worked and it was hard to decide which one was the correct solution. I marked this as my answer as it most closely resembles what I used in my code. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can join the tables and use a `CASE` expression for the result:

```
select z.*,
  case 
    when c.id is null then concat('(NOT IN serving): ', z.cityname)
    else concat('(IN serving): ', c.serving)
  end result 
from zipcodes z left join city c
on find_in_set(z.cityname, c.serving)
order by z.id
```

I used the function [`find_in_set()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) instead of the operator `like` which would need concatenating wildcards.
See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/gBHUtbKcUksZjD2Mzzpu4x/4).
Results:

```
| id  | zipcode | cityname    | result                                         |
| --- | ------- | ----------- | ---------------------------------------------- |
| 1   | 00000   | Athens      | (IN serving): Athens, Etowah, Madisonville     |
| 2   | 00001   | Dayton      | (NOT IN serving): Dayton                       |
| 3   | 00002   | Soddy Daisy | (IN serving): Soddy Daisy, Decatur, Graysville |
```

Comment: Thank you for the very detailed explanation and the literal output of my question. Also for providing a superb example. It helped me a lot towards utilizing the answers to solve my problem. Thank you!